# When is it better to run Flat Armor Seals on an AP Mid rather than +AP or Mana Regen?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm expanding into AP Mid as a new role, and I'm curious as to what other players think about this. I assume it's better for when I'm going to play more passive, but beyond that, what should I look for in terms of matchups?

Edit: I suppose I'm looking for more general advice, depending on the composition of the enemy team.

Comment: Are you focusing on any one champ in particular or are you looking for more a more generalized answer?

Comment: This is question might be too general.  You could focus it by asking about specific champions or matchups.

Answer (score 2):

I have a rune page with armor yellows for when I know I am running against an AD mid.  With solo Q you never know what you will face.

For example yesterday I faced a Talon mid as Veigar and I ran armor yellows.  I was able to out-trade him and get an early game advantage.  ( of course I underestimated his lvl 6 burst and we ended up being pretty even throughout most of the game :) )

For rune pages in general it really does depend on the champ so I would take any answer here with a grain of salt.

But in general I think that **flat mana regen is almost always better than mana regen per level.**  This is because mana regen for most AP champs is most difficult in the first 6 levels.  By the time you get to the point where per level runes are better you should have blue buff and potentially have items that compensate.  In the first 6 levels you want enough mana to harass and out-damage your opponent.

The other thing to consider is potentially going **flat magic resist blues** in order to **out-harass** your opponent (of course only if you are facing an AP champ).  An early game CS advantage is extremely important so that magic resistance can really make a difference.  And just as above with mana regen, flat is a good choice to get the upper hand in the first 6 levels.

**For quints movement speed** is often the best choice on many ap-mid champs.  This is especially true when facing an opponent with skill shots (Karthus, Morgana, Anivia, etc).  More movement makes it easier to dodge those skill shots which can be the difference between winning and losing the lane.  Movement speed quints will sometimes make you faster than the enemy jungler making it easier to escape ganks.

I wouldn't worry too much about the enemy team composition when considering runes.  It is most important to pick a rune page based on your lane match-up.

Answer (score 0):

Almost never. Only if you think that there is going to be lane swaps with top lane and you will be facing an AD bruiser.  Generally you should be taking either MR Yellows or AP Yellows.  There are champs that like tanky runes, but in mid the right way to go for tanky runes is MR since you're countering your laning opponent's damage. Armor doesn't do that.  If you find yourself wanting it near mid game just get Zhonya's hourglass. Good examples of tanky APs are Swain, Ahri, Soraka, Ryze and Galio.

Answer (score 0):

When you're playing against a champion with sustained damage output. Champions such as Ryze, Cassiopeia, and Anivia will mix in autoattacks with their spells to deal maximum damage. When you run armor seals, you can afford to trade autoattacks against them because theirs will do less damage to you. With this situation in mind, you can potentially outplay them by using your autoattacks to their fullest effect. Also, melee champions such as Gragas or Kassadin can run them in lane if they expect to take a lot of harass from autoattacks against champions like Annie/Anivia with large autoattack ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Beside Karthus, I'd never take AP seals (secondary, not that good) and on Karthus, you only get AP/lvl.

On most AP Mids, you want Mreg/lvl, on some you can take flat Mreg, but thats personal preference really. If you figure you dont need that much Manareg early, get the scaling ones, they are simply better late game.

You can take Armor seals on meeles without spammable spells (Gragas and Kassadin come to mind first). I would recommend it against enemys that Autoattack, especially when they have an AD jungler. Lets say you play Kassadin against Ahri or TF and the enemy has a Lee Sin jungle. In this scenario, you can definitly take Armor seals. But if the enemy has a non-autoattacking mid (Karthus Cassio), you shouldn't take Armor seals.

Answer (score 0):

You will very rarely take Armor runes as an AP Mid. You'll also very rarely take AP Seals as an AP Mid (though this depends on the champion).

The basic generic rune page for AP carries is: Flat Magic Pen Marks, MP5 per level Seals, AP per level, and Flat AP Quints. Everything outside of that is entirely situational. For Example, You're playing Kennen mid. Kennen doesn't use mana, thus wouldn't need MP5 seals. Some people would use MR per level, or Energy Regeneration seals instead. Some people prefer to use AP seals with high burst champions too, like Annie for example. The best thing to do if you're worried about what is situationally appropriate would be to check out some guides on [LolPro](http://www.lolpro.com) or [SoloMid](http://www.solomid.net/guides.php)

Taking armor seals as an AP Mid character would only be viable if you're playing against an AD champion, and even then you're probably still going to take MP5/Level runes just so you can harass all day without worrying too much about mana. You'll rarely see ADs in mid, and when you do you should just play carefully and harass into a burst combo. Most ADs are squishy and can't handle the damage output of an AP carry in lane.

All of that being said, some of it can come down to personal preference. Such as one answer here suggesting movement speed quints over the standard flat AP quints.